# Boundedness of gradient

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$ is such that $|\langle f(x),y\rangle|\leq C|x||y|$ holds for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

Then, there exists a fixed positive constant $C$ such that
$$
|f(x)|\leq C|x|,\,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^N.
$$

I tried to prove this way: We can write
$$
|f(x)|=\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\{0\}}\frac{|\langle f(x),y\rangle|}{|y|}.
$$
Hence, using the given condition $|\langle f(x),y\rangle|\leq C|x||y|$, we get $|f(x)|\leq\frac{C|x||y|}{|y|}=C|x|$. Therefore, the result follows.

Please inform me if I am missing something. Thanks.

Comment: how could $\langle f(x), y\rangle$ be well-defined with $f(x) \in \mathbb R$ and $y \in \mathbb R^N$ ?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question now. $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Must $\mathbf y \neq \mathbf 0$? does it specify it?

Comment: still not true as stated: just take $f(x) =x$ to see why it's false. A nonzero linear function never has bounded image.

Answer (score -1):

Since The hypothesis is true for all $\mathbf x, \mathbf y \in \mathbb R^n$ then it's true for $\mathbf y = \mathbf 0$.

So let $\mathbf y = \mathbf 0$.

$$\Vert ( \mathbf f( \mathbf x),\mathbf y)\Vert= \Vert ( \mathbf f( \mathbf x),\mathbf 0)\Vert = \Vert\mathbf f( \mathbf x)\Vert \le C \,\Vert \mathbf x\Vert \, \Vert\mathbf y\Vert= C \,\Vert \mathbf x\Vert \, \Vert\mathbf 0\Vert=0.$$

Hence $\Vert\mathbf f( \mathbf x)\Vert \le 0$, which implies that $\Vert\mathbf f( \mathbf x)\Vert = 0$.

Therefore, for all $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$, $\Vert\mathbf f( \mathbf x)\Vert \le C$ for any $C \ge 0$.

---

Edit:

I don't know whether it was supposed to be the case that $\mathbf y \neq \mathbf 0$; in that case take $\mathbf y = \mathbf e_i$, so:
$$\Vert \mathbf f(\mathbf x)\Vert \le \Vert (\mathbf f (\mathbf x),\mathbf e_i)\Vert \le C \, \Vert \mathbf x\Vert \, \Vert \mathbf e_i\Vert=C \, \Vert \mathbf x\Vert$$

Comment: Thanks. Do you think whether the argument I wrote is correct?

Comment: @P.Garain not really, you took a supremum when you should consider the function for all $\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @P.Garain Are you sure you wrote down everything correctly? the question you asked is a bit weird.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I missed $|x|$ in the claim. Please see the edited version. Hope, now its fine.

Comment: @P.Garain I see... it's not that there is anything wrong; but, as described, $\mathbf 
 f(\mathbf x)= \mathbf 0$. Not very interesting.